# Why is ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue> implementing IDictionary<TKey, TValue>?

Tags: .net, immutable-collections

It looks like a weird design choice, because a `Dictionary` and an `ImmutableDictionary` are quite different write-wise. (Read-wise, they both implement `IReadOnlyDictionary`, which is fine*)

In fact, the current implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add()` in the `ImmutableDictionary` class throws a `NewSupportedException`.

So, what was the point in doing this? If a method returns an `IDictionary` that is in fact an `ImmutableDictionary`, you're going to have some troubles when adding elements in it, for instance.

**except for the name of the interface, which is subject to debate*

Comment: So the documentation is just plain wrong?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn455946(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: I suspect it's so that the `ImmutableDictionary` can be easily dropped into code without people having to worry they're calling methods that take `IDictionary` even though it doesn't mutate the dictionary. Otherwise they'd have to make more changes. It's not ideal, but it's (slightly) pragmatic!

Comment: @Paparazzi Indeed, the documentation link you give is wrong, decompilation shows the an exception is thrown. See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/21fd3b96ff8c470cb4f98c316821060c8ef25944/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableDictionary_2.cs

Comment: @Sean: the trouble is that in code that uses the IDictionary<,>.Add() method, an exception will be thrown if you change the concrete underlying object to an ImmutableDictionary, so you'll have some worries at runtime.

Comment: @VincentRipoll - that's right. But passing something you know is an `ImmutableDictionary` to a method that tries to add to the dictionary probably isn't a good idea, either.

Comment: IReadOnlyDictionary was not an interface that they *liked* to add.  But they had to in .NET 4.5, it was necessary to implement the language projection that makes WinRT work, it projects IMapView.  Whether the project was started too soon or they followed the design rule that dictionaries should implement IDictionary is something you'll have to ask the designers.